# iOS JSQMessagesViewController Elastic Cell Behaviour

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Does anyone know how I can make the cells in JSQMessagesViewController behave in an elastic manner? An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found here:

https://dribbble.com/shots/1901175-Chat-Animation

I have had a look at the documentation and I think it is something to do with JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell Class.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing build into JSQMessageViewController controller that would let you achieve this as of yet. But it would be an awesome feature. If you figure out how to achieve it you should pull request it and get it added to the project.